Emulate evdev inside a container
If I create a mount namespace with unshare or a more sophisticated tool like Docker, can I emulate an input device using a userspace process on the host?
I'm aware of /dev/uinput as a mechanism for emulating input devices, but it doesn't hew to any sort of namespacing (to my knowledge).
Instead, I would like to mount a normal file inside the container, but somehow handle ioctls done on it, and in doing so act like evdev to simulate an input device.
Is such a thing possible on Linux? Am I missing something in my understanding (ioctls are pretty mysterious to me)?

Perhaps if you shared what it was that you hoped to achieve with this capability someone might be able to suggest  less painful route to your goal?

@symcbean does that mean it's possible but painful? :) the goal is to simulate input devices for processes inside the container, without those input devices appearing on the host (as they would with uinput)


but it doesn't hew to any sort of namespacing (to my knowledge).

It would use the same sort of namespacing as the rest of /dev – filesystem-based. Once you create an uinput device, which then shows up as an evdev device node at /dev/input/event*, you can bind-mount that device node into the container's /dev (or mknod a new one with identical major:minor number).
CUSE is the Linux interface for userspace emulation of generic character-devices, and creating a FUSE filesystem that exposes a single chardev file should also let you do the same.

Hi, can you elaborate on the procedure here for FUSE/CUSE? I've tried creating a fuse filesystem with one character device in it, and implementing the ioctl callback for fuse. I haven't tried messing with CUSE directly. I get ENXIO when I try to run evtest on that character device, without my ioctl callback getting hit.

Additionally, I don't see a way to use cuse from within a container without mounting /dev/{fuse,cuse} inside the container, which would defeat the purpose.
